# How to prevent assigning click event on child items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made an click event for `.menu li` which has `ul` in it using `$(".menu li:has(ul)")`. It works but it also assigns the same event to `.menu li ul li`. I tried using `e.stopPropagation();`, `e.PreventDefault();` and `return false;` inside function but that didn't worked at all. How to prevent that?

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FApku/) to show up actual problem.

jQuery I used:

```
$(".menu li:has(ul)").click(function() {
    console.log('has ul');
    if($(this).children("ul").is(':visible')){
        $(this).children("ul").slideUp();
    }else{
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown();
    }
});
```

Comment: The "Australia" example in your fiddle doesn't actually have its own child ul, so the click handler isn't bound to it - when you click on it it has no handler but the click event is propagating to the "Countries" container. Notice you don't get the same behaviour with "United States", which _does_ contain a ul element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('.menu a').click(function() {
    var next=$(this).next();
    if(next.prop('tagName')=='UL') {
        if(next.is(':visible')){
            next.slideUp();
        }else{
           next.slideDown();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Works now [Fiddle](http://goo.gl/JE7GP) you need to add return false on child UL